# GetGUIThreadInfo() with pywin32

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, ctypes, pywin32

I am trying to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11901591/5510469) and i have reached the point where a should call

```
GetGUIThreadInfo()
```

but i cannot find that in the [pywin32 docomentation](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html) i am using.

What i have done so far is

```
import win32api
import win32gui
import win32process

test1 = win32gui.FindWindowEx(0, 0, 0, "notepad")
(test1tid, test1pid) = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(test1)
test1hwndFocus = win32process.GetGUIThreadInfo(test1tid)
```

but the last line is compleatly made up as i cannot find the right way to call the function.

Update1:

Think i made some progress but now my struct just returns 0 when i expect some hwnd... so maybe my struct is not writen to, i think this could be because of the types in my struct, but how do i find the right types?

```
import win32api
import win32gui
import win32process
import ctypes

class RECT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
    ("left", ctypes.c_ulong),
    ("top", ctypes.c_ulong),
    ("right", ctypes.c_ulong),
    ("bottom", ctypes.c_ulong)
    ]


class GUITHREADINFO(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
    ("cbSize", ctypes.c_ulong),
    ("flags", ctypes.c_ulong),
    ("hwndActive", ctypes.c_ulong),
    ("hwndFocus", ctypes.c_ulong),
    ("hwndCapture", ctypes.c_ulong),
    ("hwndMenuOwner", ctypes.c_ulong),
    ("hwndMoveSize", ctypes.c_ulong),
    ("hwndCaret", ctypes.c_ulong),
    ("rcCaret", RECT)
    ]

guiThreadInfoStruct = GUITHREADINFO()


ctypes.sizeof(gtitest)

test1 = win32gui.FindWindowEx(0, 0, 0, "notepad")
(test1tid, test1pid) = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(test1)
ctypes.windll.user32.GetGUIThreadInfo(test1tid, guiThreadInfoStruct)
print (guiThreadInfoStruct.hwndFocus)
```

Update2:

I found the types [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-guithreadinfo)

update3:

If anyone wanna see what i used this for go look [here](https://github.com/sth0r/pyboxer-keystroke-broadcaster)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, [[MS.Docs]: GetGUIThreadInfo function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getguithreadinfo) is not wrapped by *PyWin32*, so alternative ways must be used. One of them is calling it via [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) (involves writing a lot of extra code).

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import win32gui as wgui
import win32process as wproc
import win32con as wcon

import ctypes as ct
from ctypes import wintypes as wt


class GUITHREADINFO(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("cbSize", wt.DWORD),
        ("flags", wt.DWORD),
        ("hwndActive", wt.HWND),
        ("hwndFocus", wt.HWND),
        ("hwndCapture", wt.HWND),
        ("hwndMenuOwner", wt.HWND),
        ("hwndMoveSize", wt.HWND),
        ("hwndCaret", wt.HWND),
        ("rcCaret", wt.RECT),

    ]

    def __str__(self):
        ret = "\n" + self.__repr__()
        start_format = "\n  {0:s}: "
        for field_name, _ in self. _fields_[:-1]:
            field_value = getattr(self, field_name)
            field_format = start_format + ("0x{1:016X}" if field_value else "{1:}")
            ret += field_format.format(field_name, field_value)
        rc_caret = getattr(self, self. _fields_[-1][0])
        ret += (start_format + "({1:d}, {2:d}, {3:d}, {4:d})").format(self. _fields_[-1][0], rc_caret.top, rc_caret.left, rc_caret.right, rc_caret.bottom)
        return ret


def main(*argv):
    window_name = "Untitled - Notepad"
    hwnd = wgui.FindWindowEx(wcon.NULL, 0, wcon.NULL, window_name)
    print("'{0:s}' window handle: 0x{1:016X}".format(window_name, hwnd))
    tid, pid = wproc.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
    print("PId: {0:d}, TId: {1:d}".format(pid, tid))

    user32_dll = ct.WinDLL("user32.dll")
    GetGUIThreadInfo = getattr(user32_dll, "GetGUIThreadInfo")
    GetGUIThreadInfo.argtypes = [wt.DWORD, ct.POINTER(GUITHREADINFO)]
    GetGUIThreadInfo.restype = wt.BOOL

    gti = GUITHREADINFO()
    gti.cbSize = ct.sizeof(GUITHREADINFO)
    res = GetGUIThreadInfo(tid, ct.byref(gti))
    print("{0:s} returned: {1:d}".format(GetGUIThreadInfo.__name__, res))
    if res:
        print(gti)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {0:s} {1:d}bit on {2:s}\n".format(" ".join(item.strip() for item in sys.version.split("\n")), 64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.")
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q059884688>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.07.06_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code00.py
> Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] 64bit on win32
>
> 'Untitled - Notepad' window handle: 0x00000000042B20D8
> PId: 37192, TId: 53072
> GetGUIThreadInfo returned: 1
>
> <__main__.GUITHREADINFO object at 0x0000022649436648>
>   cbSize: 0x0000000000000048
>   flags: 0
>   hwndActive: None
>   hwndFocus: None
>   hwndCapture: None
>   hwndMenuOwner: None
>   hwndMoveSize: None
>   hwndCaret: None
>   rcCaret: (0, 0, 0, 0)
>
> Done.
> ```

**Notes**:

- *print* data that you are working with, as it might be different what you'd expect. For example, the *Notepad* window title is not "*notepad*" like your code expects it to be, and in that case *win32gui.FindWindowEx* would return *NULL* (0).
- I also use [[ActiveState.Docs]: PyWin32 Documentation](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.6/pywin32/PyWin32.HTML) (it's old and outdated, but in most cases it's extremely helpful)

Comment: Can i do both? it did solve the problem, but i do not understand parts of the solution, i want to make it into a function taking the hwnd as an input and returning hwndFocus, but i do not want the answer but maybe ask for a bit of clarification

Comment: i do not realy get what this does?

GetGUIThreadInfo = getattr(user32_dll, "GetGUIThreadInfo")

Comment: and when something takes self as an input what does that mean?

Comment: To answer the 1st comment: it searches for the function with the given name in the loaded *.dll* instance. But it's covered in the *CTypes* *URL* (in the answer). As for the 2nd comment: check https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html.